# Selenium Grid 2 not running test case

Tags: visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, browser-automation, selenium-grid2

I have successfully set up Selenium GRID using Remote WebDriver which worked perfectly when using it locally without connecting to a remote node. If both the hub and the node are on the same machine it runs fine, but running a remote node only opens the browser without running the actual test. I am running this in this environment - Windows 8 (hub), both remote and local nodes are Windows 8.

This is the simple test:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://MYIPADDRESS:4466/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com");
```

when I debugged, I kept getting this error - `Additional information: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:`

I'm surprised for wanting to connect to localhost because I'm not using localhost but the IP address. How do I get it to run?

Comment: just guessing here, but it sounds like your version of firefox is not compatible with the version if selenium you are using.  I would check to make sure the version of firefox is the same as what you were running on your local machine.  It is possible that firefox auto-updated as well, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Your guess is right. I have long upgraded it when I read about the problem on a forum. That solved the problem. Thanks.